# 「〜てすむ」の意味は何ですか。

Tags: grammar

「ほってすんでいました」の文法を詳しく説明していただけませんか。「すむ」の漢字は「済む」でしょうか。

> 例）「陸に上がったクモはしばらくのあいだ、地面にあなを**ほってすんでいました**。」

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「[住]{す}む」です。

「地面に[穴]{あな}を[掘]{ほ}って、その穴の[中]{なか}に[住]{す}んでいました。」という意味です。

（「穴を掘る」は、地面を掘って、穴を作ることです。）